# Android Virtual Device Not Detecting Code Changes After Hot Reload And Hot Restart - Flutter

Tags: android-studio, flutter, dart

I have been working on an app using **flutter**, everything was working fine until out of a sudden the android phone stopped detecting code changes when using hot reload and hot restart.

in order to make it detect these changes i have to stop the run phase and then run it again, like uninstall and install the app again, i tried **invalidating the cache and restarting the android studio** and **tried `flutter clean`** and i also tried **wiping the virtual device's data**, but nothing worked.

any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Can you please share code that you added between the time when it worked and time it stopped working? Can it be that you are using compile time variables, that are not changed on hot reload and that's what's causing the issue?

Comment: @Aleksandar well this is the idea, i didn't add anything weird or something i mean i'm still working on the ui haven't added anything yet, just normal code and widgets

Comment: Check for updates if any.

Comment: @dev-aentgs ok I will